# UWP: LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync not work when running in Kiosk mode

Tags: uwp, kiosk-mode

I have a simple UWP: a page with a button.
On button click event I do the following:

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
{
    await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
}
```

that executes a WPF.

When I run the UWP all works perfectly.
Whet I run the UWP in kiosk mode, after I click on the button, the WPF is no executed.

Are fullTrustProcess supported in kiosk mode?

I just checked with EventViewer that actually the WPF application was executed without errors but in it was showed on top of UWP application...
... I tryed to set the **TopMost** attribute to WPF window but it didn't work!

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the kiosk mode that your device is using. It seems that you are using **a single-app kiosk** which means the device runs a UWP app on the full screen above the lock screen. If it is, then this behavior is expected because only the UWP will be shown. I'd suggest you just use one application. If you need to do some work in the desktop app, just pass the result back and show the result in the UWP app.